# Fill list of numbers with zeros Python

Tags: python, list

I have a  list of numbers such as:

```
test_list = [1,5,6,8,10]
```

I want to fill this list with zeros so that the numbers are still in order, but the list has a length of 15 such as:

```
new_list = [1,0,0,0,5,6,0,8,0,10,0,0,0,0,0]
```

How would I do that?

Comment: I am unsure of how to actually fill a list with anything, so I am open to any suggestions!

Comment: Is the position of the zeroes important?

Comment: Are the numbers in sequence and the gaps need to be zero?

Comment: Yes, so my initial list includes the height index, so where there is a number, there is a value associated with that at a certain height. So say there are 15 height layers, if there is a 5 in that list, that means there is a value at that layer. Therefore, the zeros must be in between the numbers to show that there are no values in those height layers

Comment: Do you understand for loops? Are you comfortable with list comprehensions?

Comment: Also, @Kate, consider editing your question to include the information in your last comment, for clarity.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a list comprehension in combination with an inline if/else:

```
[i if i in test_list else 0 for i in range(1, 16)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension with `range` to check for inclusion in the original list. If the numbers will always be between 1-15 it would look like this:

```
test_list = [1,5,6,8,10]
new_list = [ x if x in test_list else 0 for x in range(1,16) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how big these lists might get, you might want to use numpy, which will be a lot faster if they can get really big, and it allows you to index an array with another array:

```
import numpy as np

test_list = np.array([1, 5, 6, 8, 10])
new_list = np.zeros(15, dtype=int)
new_list[test_list - 1] = test_list
new_list

array([ 1,  0,  0,  0,  5,  6,  0,  8,  0, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can think about it in steps. First we have to initialize a list with all zeros. Then we can fill it with the values you want at the locations you want.

```
# Here's your test list
test_list = [1,5,6,8,10]

# Create a list of length 15 with all zeros
my_list = [0]*15

# Fill in the list with the values you have, you may want to check 
# to make sure the value is in-bounds
for value in test_list:
    if value <= 15 and value >= 1:
        my_list[value-1] = value
    else:
        raise IndexError('Index ' + str(value) + ' is out of bounds!')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#To insert random number of zeros between elements.    
import random
t = [1,5,6,8,10]  
#Generate a list of "list with one element of t and rand num of 0s"  
a = [ [x] + [0]*random.randint(1,4) for x in t] 
# a is list of list, and we do not want that. So, flatten out  
# the each element of a and add them into list b.
b = []
for x in a: b = b + x
print('t', t)
print('b', b)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Ajean, Edited the answer with additional context. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To create the output that you have, a simple `for` loop could also be used as follows:

```
test_list = [1, 5, 6, 8, 10]
new_list = [0] * 15     # create an empty list of 15 entries

for x in test_list:
    new_list[x - 1] = x

print new_list
```

This would display the following output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

If you wanted to associate a particular value with each index, then you could do this using a list of tuple pairs as follows:

```
# Index,Value pairs
test_list = [(1, 10), (5, 3), (6, 5), (8, 1), (10, 2)]
new_list = [0] * 15

for index, value in test_list:
    new_list[index - 1] = value

print new_list
```

This would then display the following:

```
[10, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```